# Post to Azure FHIR Server method Fail to Authentication Failed 401

Tags: javascript, azure, http, post, hl7-fhir

I have an Azure FHIR Server which I have tested with POSTMAN I am able to Read Patients as well as POST Patients using POSTMAN and Oauth token.

I have now created a JavaScript Post method so that I can post data from my own method rather than using POSTMAN. 
I have followed the basic guidance from here [Creating a resource](http://build.fhir.org/overview-dev.html) 
I can get an access token using POSTMAN and I use that access token in my POST method.

My method and post data is as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  (async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://smarthealth.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient', {
  method: 'POST',
  Authorization: 'Bearer DGRijc8LrnjCrhRFRSn2Jnf89q2wGT_gxNHtJt',
   headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'
                },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    "resourceType": "Patient",
    "id": "9184e31a-a2b3-4b8d-9032-d5377cabaa08",

       "extension": [
         {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race",
            "extension": [
               {
                "url": "ombCategory",
              "valueCoding": {
               "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
             "code": "2106-3",
             "display": "White"
                }
                  },
           {
             "url": "text",
           "valueString": "White"
                         }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
              "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-birthPlace",
        "valueAddress": {
         "city": "Mashpee",
          "state": "Massachusetts",
          "country": "US"
                            }
                        },

                    ],

                    "name": [
                        {
                            "use": "official",
                            "family": "Kutch",
                            "given": [
                                "Sherron"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],

                    "gender": "female",
                    "birthDate": "2009-04-29",

                })
            });
            const content = await rawResponse.json();

            console.log(content);
        })();

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Javascript Azure FHIR Post Request Test
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Authentication Failed Image here]

Comment: I think you are not sending token in right way, `Authorization: 'Bearer DGRijc8LrnjCrhRFRSn2Jnf89q2wGT_gxNHtJt'` I doubt this line.

Comment: Yes, where exactly are you getting that token from?

Comment: @MichaelHansen i am using POSTMAN to retrieve token and then using it in my method. it works fine in POSTMAN.

Comment: That does not look like a valid token. What do the return headers say (you can check that in Fiddler or something like that).

Comment: And like the previous commenter, it does not look like you are adding that header in the correct way. Why is it not with the other headers. I would check in Fiddler to make sure you actually are sending the token the right way (and make sure it is indeed a valid token).

Comment: @MichaelHansen I have edited out token to fit the post and for security reasons i did not wish to post my original token.

Comment: Still, I don't think the way you are adding the header is correct. I would verify in Fiddler (you can compare Postman to your code) and see you are adding it in the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try sending your request according to below format.

```
  $("#btnPostToAzureFHIR").click(function () {
        var yourPostDataFormat = {
            resourceType: "Patient",
            id: "9184e31a-a2b3-4b8d-9032-d5377cabaa08"
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://smarthealth.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient",
            data: JSON.stringify(yourPostDataFormat),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer DGRijc8LrnjCrhRFRSn2Jnf89q2wGT_gxNHtJt');
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
```

> **Note:** Bind your parameter in key value pair on `yourPostDataFormat` then pass on `JSON.stringify(yourPostDataFormat)`
>   section. Hope it would post your request with token

Comment: your click button function did not work for me as it would throw error I had to do, Do you happen to know how would i post a JSON file rather then JSON data itself ?          
                                                                                                                                      
        var  yourPostDataFormat = {
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "9184e31a-a2b3-4b8d-9032-d5377cabaa08",
  "meta": {
    "versionId": "3",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-06-06T02:51:49.378-04:00"}

Comment: I am not concern't about the click button focus on `beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer DGRijc8LrnjCrhRFRSn2Jnf89q2wGT_gxNHtJt');
            }` which is the valid way to pass token on server. You are getting unauthorized because your token couldn't reach to server.

Comment: Since i set my data to a variable it worked i can now post to Server. But rather then pasting JSON data i would like to post JSON file.

Comment: I understand. Glad to help you.